# Using jQuery Off and On in Chain Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know if this syntax is possible. (To use off and on methods in a chain format like below?) I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` when doing this :/

```
slider.off('change').on('change', function(values, handle) {

     // Do something

}
```

Comment: Yes this is valid.  Can you make a working example of your issue?

Comment: It's possible, but it makes no sense to use it unless you are changing the callback to another one. The `.off()` method call will immediately be replaced by the `.on()` call.

Comment: I think you want [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)